# Enable and Disable tab using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to enable and disable tab based select results.Below the code I am working.If device B status is On-Line I need to disable Device-V tab.How to implement this using JavaScript/jQuery.

jQuery:

```
if(result.includes("On-line") ){
    $(selected_device_id).html("");
    //Need to implement disable function here
     $(selected_device_id).append(result+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&#9989;");
```

HTML File:

```
<div class="panel">
   <br>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs">
   <li class="active">
      <a
         data-toggle="tab"
         href="#Device-B"
         onclick="document.getElementById('Object').value = '';
         document.getElementById('first_i').value = '';
         document.getElementById('second_i').value = '';
         document.getElementById('third_i').value = '';">
      <i>
      <b>Device B</b>
      </i>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a
         data-toggle="tab"
         href="#Device-V"
         onclick="document.getElementById('tr181_object').value = '';
         document.getElementById('first_i').value = '';
         document.getElementById('second_i').value = '';
         document.getElementById('third_i').value = '';">
      <i>
      <b>Video</b>
      </i>
      </a>
   </li>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks. You'll have to modify the href attribute.

Comment: ok.I can disable tab with     $('.nav li').not('.active').addClass('disabled');
    $('.nav li').not('.active').find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");

Comment: but Problem is based on device A or Deice V it has to disable.Now it is disabling active tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
     var switch_ch = 0 ; 
       $(".linktoggle").on("click",function(){
     
         i = $(this).index(".linktoggle") ; 
         if( $(".linktoggle").attr("href") === "#Device-B")
           {
              
               if( switch_ch ===  0 ) 
               {
                 $(".linktoggle:eq(0)").show();
                 $("li:eq(0)").show();
                 $(".linktoggle:eq(1)").hide();
                 $("li:eq(1)").hide();
                   switch_ch = 1 ;
               }
               else 
               {
                 $(".linktoggle:eq(1)").show();
                 $("li:eq(1)").show();
                
                
                 switch_ch = 0 ;
               
               }
              
           }
           
        if( $(".linktoggle").attr("href") === "#Device-V")
           {
                 $(".linktoggle:eq("+i +")").hide();
               
           }
          
     });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <div class="panel">
          <br>

              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
              <a
                class="linktoggle"
                href="#Device-B" >
                <i>
                  <b>Device B</b>
                </i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                class="linktoggle"
                data-toggle="tab"
                href="#Device-V"
                          >
                <i>
                  <b>Video</b>
                </i>
              </a>
            </li>
         </div>
```

Comment: I am trying with below code.                       $("#PA").tabs({
                        active: 2,
                        disabled: [0, 1]
                    });

Comment: But getting tabs is a not a function.